# Accessing return value of class method from Trigger

Tags: apex, trigger, map

I am new to apex. I have written an apex class with a single method. The method returns a map`(<Lead>, Set<Date>>).`

Question: After running the method from within the trigger, how do I access the returned Map?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data that is returned from your method needs to be stored in a variable and then you can operate on it.

```
trigger myLeadTrigger on Lead (before insert, before update) {

    // do some work and store the return data
    Map<Lead, Set<Date>> leadDatesMap = yourClass.yourMethod(Trigger.new);

    // do something with the returned data
    for (Lead l : leadDatesMap.keyset()) {
        Set<Date> leadDates = leadDatesMap.get(l);
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks! And may I ask why you had to put "Trigger.new" in parameters during the map declaration?

Comment: It's just for demonstration... usually the methods called from your triggers use the collection of data from the trigger. This is just one way to access the data from the trigger in your method.

Comment: In my case I store the records from Trigger.new into a list, and then use the list as a parameter for this method.

In that case would I just write the following in my Map declaration?:

Map<Lead, Set<Date>> leadDatesMap = yourClass.yourMethod

Comment: Same difference. Trigger.new is a list, your way works great too.